# Asana returns spurious 500 errors with cryptic messages

Tags: asana, asana-api

I am seeing spurious HTTP 500 errors with cryptic messages. For example, doing a GET using oauth on /projects/28408740055707 I see a response body: {"errors":[{"message":"Server Error","phrase":"24 purple woodchucks wriggle fast"}]}

I've also seen it on GET /tasks/{taskId}/stories  and other endpoints as well.  Any thoughts on this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an API call or an action within the Asana application generates a server error we generate a random phrase that corresponds so that we can easily look up logs about the issue later.

If you continue to experience 500 errors when making calls to the API we encourage you to write into api-support@asana.com and reference the error phrase along with the call that you were making so that we can try to fix the issue.

I checked for "24 purple woodchucks wriggle fast" and that specific issue seems to have been solved.